# octokit.net : Create a new commit

Tags: c#, git, octokit.net

I have created a repository and with [octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) and I want to **create a new commit** with the 'full commit' method. I have successfully created a 'one file / one line' commit following [this tutorial](http://laedit.net/2016/11/12/GitHub-commit-with-Octokit-net.html).
But the 'full commit' section is not working. I'm using Octokit version **0.24.1-alpha0001**.

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Octokit" Version="0.24.1-alpha0001"/>
```

My code is here :

```cs
var Client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("my-cool-app"));
var Owner = "Owner";
var RepositoryName = "RepositoryName";
var Password = "Password";
Client.Credentials = new Credentials(Owner, Password);
```

After, I create a repository with this.

```cs
var context = Client.Repository.Create(repository);
```

And here is my 'full commit' section :

```cs
using Octokit;
try {
    // 1. Get the SHA of the latest commit of the master branch.
    var headMasterRef = "heads/master";               
    var masterReference = Client.Git.Reference.Get(Owner, RepositoryName, headMasterRef).Result; // Get reference of master branch
    var latestCommit = Client.Git.Commit.Get(Owner, RepositoryName, 
    masterReference.Object.Sha).Result; // Get the laster commit of this branch
    var nt = new NewTree { BaseTree = latestCommit.Tree.Sha };

    //2. Create the blob(s) corresponding to your file(s)
    var textBlob = new NewBlob { Encoding = EncodingType.Utf8, Content = "Hellow World!" };
    var textBlobRef = Client.Git.Blob.Create(Owner, RepositoryName, textBlob);

    // 3. Create a new tree with:
    nt.Tree.Add(new NewTreeItem { Path = fileRel.RelativePath, Mode = "100644", Type = TreeType.Blob, Sha = textBlobRef.Result.Sha });
    var newTree = Client.Git.Tree.Create(Owner, RepositoryName, nt).Result;

    // 4. Create the commit with the SHAs of the tree and the reference of master branch
    // Create Commit
    var newCommit = new NewCommit("Commit test with several files", newTree.Sha, masterReference.Object.Sha);
    var commit = Client.Git.Commit.Create(Owner, RepositoryName, newCommit).Result;

    // 5. Update the reference of master branch with the SHA of the commit
    // Update HEAD with the commit
    Client.Git.Reference.Update(Owner, RepositoryName, headMasterRef, new ReferenceUpdate(commit.Sha));
} catch (AggregateException e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"An exception is detected in the commit step. {e.Message}");
}
```

There is no exception, everything seems defined but when I go to the master branch of my repository, no commit is done. There is just the initial commit.

Comment: The git object (newTree, commit) are ok?
I haven't tried it since the article, maybe the API have changed.

Comment: Yes, both newTree and commit objects are correctly defined. I see the repo on github but the commit isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. I was missing the **.Result** at the Client.Git.Reference.Update line. This works nice. Thanks **Jérémie Bertrand**.

I updated

```cs
// 5. Update the reference of master branch with the SHA of the commit
// Update HEAD with the commit
Client.Git.Reference.Update(Owner, RepositoryName, headMasterRef, new 
ReferenceUpdate(commit.Sha));
```

to this code

```cs
Client.Git.Reference.Update(Owner, RepositoryName, headMasterRef, new 
ReferenceUpdate(commit.Sha)).Result;
```

I discovered it with a breakpoint on the git object (newTree, commit) : urls were here. The tutorial is correct because it uses **await** :

```cs
await github.Git.Reference.Update(owner, repo, headMasterRef, new ReferenceUpdate(commit.Sha));
```